# How to model adiabatic lapse rate from first principles?

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, atmospheric-science, adiabatic

As a motivating example, consider that the grand canyon floor is ~11ºC warmer than the top. The dry adiabatic lapse rate of 9.8ºC/km, at the average depth of 1.2km deep, implies a 11.76ºC warmer floor which nearly fully explains the difference.

My question is, how would one model it from first principles, i.e. not putting a fixed factor of 9.8ºC/km in the model, but rather modeling the processes such that the *result* is a 9.8ºC/km gradient?

With just the solar input, the floor and the top would get to about the same temperature (ignoring shadows for now).

How, precisely, does the air & surface get hotter as a result of the lapse rate? As far as I can understand it is like this:

- The surface (say the bottom) heats up from the Sun
- This in term heats a thin layer of air via conduction
- The air heats up
- Because there is no hard boundary on the air, it expands and cools, lowering the density
- Because gravity has caused a pressure gradient in the atmosphere, the cool air rises. This upwards force does work on the air (?)
- Later (?), gravity exerts force on the cooler air, driving it downwards, exchanging potential energy for kinetic energy (?), which heats the air up as well as compressing it causing it to heat further (?)

I am fuzzy on the details of where the work performed comes into play, how relevant the potential energy and kinetic energy of the air is, and also how the latter part of the process doesn't describe a perpetual motion machine. I suppose if it weren't for the Sun's energy in the first place, the air on the bottom wouldn't heat up and expand and cool as a result... but gravity is also causing the air to heat up?

Comment: The (dry) adiabatic lapse rate can indeed be derived from first principles considering the thermodynamics of adiabatic processes, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate). What you get is $\Gamma_d = g/c_p$ where both of these are known parameters.